# How can i shift characters places with another array in C?

Tags: c, caesar-cipher

Hey guys so I need to replace the character that the users had inputed plus 3 like in caesar cipher. For example: A will become C, B = D, C = F and so on but my output is wrong, it prints random characters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

char codificador(char fraseUsuario[15]){
char confereFrase[15];
int tamanho = lstrlen(fraseUsuario);
int cont = 0;
char alfabeto[27] = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','w','y','z'};
char cifraCezar[27] = {'d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','x','w','y','z','a','b','c'};



//Passa o valor do vetor original para o vetor comparativo
while(cont != tamanho){
    confereFrase[cont] = fraseUsuario[cont];
    cont++;
    }
    cont = 0;
//Codifica a mensagem usando a cifra
while(cont!= tamanho){
    confereFrase[cifraCezar[cont]];
    cont++;
    }

printf("%s",confereFrase);



}



int main(){
char mensagemUsuario[50];
char fraseUsuario[30];
char senha[10];
printf("Digite sua mensagem: ");
fflush(stdin);
gets(fraseUsuario);
codificador(fraseUsuario);


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "but i can't get it to work properly" is **not** a valid question

Comment: why isn't it a valid question?

Comment: Because before asking here you should debug your program. While doing so, you can spot where your logic fails. Considering that you did not mention what and where happens differently than you would assume, I think you did not debug your program at all

Comment: @FelipeLima [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) explains how to ask questions in a way that is easier to answer.

Comment: Sorry, I started learning C and programming recently so I don't have the "know-how" yet. I did debug, what's happening is that the output gives me random characters different than I expected to got but I don't understand what's wrong with my code. I just need someone more experient to point out what's wrong so I can try to fix it. Sorry

Comment: if your output gives you different characters than expected, you should use your debugger to see where are they becoming 'unexpected'. This way you can focus on a single part of the code that misbehaves

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Everything in C is an integer. As follows, works only for lower case. Exercise for the reader to add support for upper case, and to detect non-character inputs before attempting the conversion etc.

```
char c = getc(STDIN);
char coded = c+3;
if( coded > 'z') coded -= 'z';
```